# Silverlight Accordion. Can I bind to set of controls with different styles?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have list of some data items. Each has a method `GetStyle` which returns `ControlTemplate`. Previously I was building a custom panel and adding the items as controls into children.

Now I need to group the items and I want to use accordion but I need to find out how can I inject my own template for each item on binding.

Alternatively I can split the items into several panels and add them to the accordion (avoiding data binding) but not sure how either.

I'm using Silverlight 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done to make it work:

- Created lookless control
- On either Load or ApplyTemplate I inject ControlTemplate into the
  control
- Created Accordion content item template as
  ...
- Bind Accordion data source to the list of items which has
  knowledge on what template has to be created.